# Flutter Google Tag Manager

Tags: flutter, google-tag-manager, flutter-dependencies

I need to implement Google Tag Manager in my current flutter app. I looked for a package but I only found this https://pub.dev/packages/google_tag_manager which is only for flutter web.

My question: Is there a way to integrate Google Tag Manager in an existing flutter app, which uses Firebase Analytics, without creating a plugin itself?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found that was following this: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5

Follow the first step and in the second step you can use the flutter firebase analytics plugin to log events normally :)